# ASP Membership / Role Provider -> how to report the number of users currently logged in?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm using the ASP.NET Membership and Role provider.  My question is about if there is a built in way to report the number of users who are currently logged in.  The question is not get the information about the user who is logged in but from a high level view of everyone who is logged in.

I would like to create a user management dashboard and this metric would be great.  also showing the usernames of users who are currently logged in would be useful.

thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there's a built-in way, see [Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getnumberofusersonline.aspx). You can change the "window" for what's considered online, see [Membership.UserIsOnlineTimeWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.userisonlinetimewindow.aspx). (you set the threshold in web.config)

**UPDATE**:

In response to your comment about getting a list of online usernames...

The Membership API is lacking what you want, so you have to roll your own. You can use the following as starter code, it's similar to what I've done in the past:

```
public static List<string> GetUsersOnline() {
  List<string> l = new List<string>();
  string CS = WebConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings[YOUR_WEB_CONFIG_KEY]
    .ConnectionString
  ;
  string sql = @"
SELECT UserName,LastActivityDate 
FROM aspnet_Users
WHERE LastActivityDate > @window 
ORDER BY LastActivityDate DESC"
  ;
  using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(CS) ) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, c) ) {
      DateTime window = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(
        -Membership.UserIsOnlineTimeWindow
      );
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@window", window);
      c.Open();
      using (SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader() ) {
        while ( r.Read() ) {
          l.Add(r.GetString(0));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return l;
}
```

A couple of notes:

- Replace `YOUR_WEB_CONFIG_KEY` above with the key in your web.config `<connectionStrings>` section.
- The `LastActivityDate` field in the `aspnet_Users` table (`aspnetdb` database) is stored as a GMT/UTC `Datetime` value, so that's why `DateTime.UtcNow` is used to calculate the window.
- Not sure how your Membership database permissions are setup, but you *may* need to make permission changes, since above code is directly querying the database.

Comment: Thanks!  that worked.  Do you know a way to get the list of username who are online?

Comment: thank you! I will play with this.  I think it is exactly what i need to get started with it =)